# error: expected identifier before '_Bool'

Tags: pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I previously had the following code when dealing with my sync tuple:

```
static void sync_tuple_changed_callback(const uint32_t key, const Tuple* new_tuple, const Tuple* old_tuple, void* context) {
  persist_write_bool(key,new_tuple->value->bool);
}
```

However, I just tried building this (in Cloud Pebble), and got the error:

```
../src/main.c: In function 'sync_tuple_changed_callback':
../src/main.c:25:44: error: expected identifier before '_Bool'
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `bool` member of the `value` union - your best bet is to use the `uint8` member instead, passing 1 for true and 0 for false:

```
static void sync_tuple_changed_callback(const uint32_t key, const Tuple* new_tuple, const Tuple* old_tuple, void* context) {
  persist_write_bool(key,new_tuple->value->uint8 != 0);
}
```